# Close TCP connection with the server when Internet connection is lost

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP server on a linux system (written in C) and a TCP client on android, when android's internet connection is lost the server doesn't seem to notice that and `send` and `recv` continue working as if nothing happened.

I already implemented heartbeat technique to check for dead connections but it's not good enough, it waits for 30 seconds before reaping dead clients and some data get lost in the process.

How do I tell the server that the connection is closed?

Comment: Imagine: How would you say "Goodbye" to sombody on the phone when he already hung up?
Answer: Not at all. No way.

Therefore this is not an android question. Sry.

Comment: The data has already been lost by the connection going down. What you're seeing is the effect of TCP buffering and retries. You should eventually see `send()` or `recv` with `errno == ECONNRESET.` Unclear what you're asking. @cybergen 'therefore this is not an Android question' is a *non sequitur.*

Comment: @EJP On the server side the connection remains alive and continue sending data (which is lost because the client is not on the other side to receive it) with no errors. I need to make the server drop the connection immediately when client loses the connection.

Comment: @EJP I just meant he should change the tags because the problem is server side and c/c++ related.

Comment: @EPJ i'm using `if (send (sockfd, buffer, strlen (buffer), 0) == -1) // error` to check for errors, not sure how to check for errno, is this definitely a server side issue?

Comment: You *can't* make the server drop the connection immediately. TCP doesn't work like that. On purpose.

Comment: The client's end of the connection was ripped away unexpectedly. The server **does not know** and **cannot know** immediately that the client is gone. That is what *graceful* closes are for. By design, TCP will keep buffering and retrying to send data until an internal timeout occurs. Your heartbeat is merely augmenting that timeout. There is also a TCP level keep-alive timer you can enable to also help detect dead connections. But you will **never** get instantaneous detection of dead connections that are not closed gracefully. A timeout period of unresponsiveness has to elapse first.

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured out a work around by making clients send confirmation messages when they receive new data, and the server to keep records of sent data till confirmation is received.